# Use Google App Engine's NDB as a message queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, message-queue, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

Has anyone tried to use NDB as a message queue? We have several consumers and producers, which may want to do broadcast, multicast, and publish-subscribe.  I've read several documents on why using a RDBMS as a message queue is bad.  But in my case, my app can tolerate latency of several seconds.  So eventual consistency should not be as much of an issue, because almost all replication in NDB should complete within a few seconds.  In terms of message ordering, I could use timestamps.

Another alternative is to use NDB's strong consistency feature with a buffer (e.g. memcache).

Comment: Why not google pub/sub service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/)?  It's optimized for both push (broadcast, multicast) and pull (subscribe).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.   I read the documentation for Task Queue, but it seemed like it was more for computational tasks.  Or is the idea that the task payload is the "message", and the request handler and app-specific URL specifies the receiver? A broadcast would basically specify multiple URLs and request handlers?  Is there an example online of using a Task Queue for communication?

Comment: I think that any useful example would have to be in the context of your own application.  Can you provide some more details on how you want to use the message queue in your question?

Comment: Suppose one web service A wants to send emails to a list of people through an email web service B.  I suppose I could use deferred tasks for this (or a Push Task Queue).   Each task would consist of a URL to the email web service, its web request handler, and a payload consisting of a message body and the receiver id.

Comment: This is a good use for the Task Queue.  If the task fails for any reason (as it sometimes happens with email delivery), it will retry again later.  I always send emails from AppEngine this way.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is a way to order task completion in a Task Queue?  I read that there is no guarantee that tasks are completed in the order that they appear in the queue, but I was wondering if there is some work around for this.

Comment: Will you create a new question with all the important details?  For example, what defines the order: a timestamp?  What if a task fails, should all the other tasks wait until it succeeds later?  This would be a useful question to ask.

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973984/how-to-execute-tasks-in-fifo-order-using-google-app-engine-task-queues